# Start uwsgi from Docker

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi

Im trying to "dockerize" my web application which uses uwsgi.

My problem is that when I run `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` from the Dockerfile it does not start the uwsgi process. 
**What am I doing wrong?**

My Dockerfile looks like this (simplified):

```
RUN mkdir /home/webapp/configuration
ADD uwsgi.ini /home/webapp/configuration
RUN uwsgi --ini /home/webapp/configuration/uwsgi.ini
```

Output when the image is build:

```
Step 26 : RUN uwsgi --ini /home/webapp/configuration/uwsgi.ini
 ---> Running in 832a29ebf40e
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/webapp/configuration/uwsgi.ini
 ---> 3125dbfb1a75
```

Its very weird that uWSGI is getting the INI configuration, but the process does not start.

Comment: ty ro replace RUN by CMD in your Dockerfile

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "/home/webapp/configuration/uwsgi.ini"]
```